# Seeing unconverted Cloudwatch Dimensions ("${aws:*}") from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an EC2 instance deployed with terraform with cloudwatch metrics setup. The following is the metrics section from `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json`

```
 "metrics": {
    "namespace": "SteveMetrics",
    "metrics_collected": {
      "cpu": {
        "measurement": [ "usage_system", "usage_user" ],
        "append_dimensions": { 
          "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}", 
          "InstanceId": "steve20230616a", 
          "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}", 
          "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Cloudwatch is receiving the metrics since I can view them when I filter on my dummy InstanceId dimension steve20230616a, however the dimensions `${aws:*}` are shown without conversion in cloudwatch, e.g. in cloudwatch the autoscaling group name is "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}" and not the name of my ASG.

From reading this amazon document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html I think the configuration file is correct and I need to allow the VPC access to the EC2 region endpoint service

> If you specify a value that depends on Amazon EC2 metadata and you use proxies, you must make sure that the server can access the endpoint for Amazon EC2.

In terraform I have added

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "ec2" {
  service = "ec2"
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ec2" {
  vpc_id            = data.aws_subnet.subnet.vpc_id
  service_name      = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.ec2.service_name
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
}
```

I presume I am making an error in the terraform or there is additional cloudwatch agent setup required, but I'm not sure what.

I have also tried adding no-proxy config `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml`

```
[proxy]
  http_proxy = "$${proxyAddr}"
  https_proxy = "$${proxyAddr}"
  no_proxy = "redacted,ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: The first bit you shared with the `metrics` object, what is that part of?

Comment: it is part of the amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json

Comment: Right, but where is that defined? Is that in your terraform config..?

Comment: Can you show us how the EC2 instance is created? Are you creating the cloudwatch agent config in the userdata?

Comment: yes the cloudwatch agent config is created in the userdata.

Comment: After the config is defined, cloudwatch is restarted and I can see it is running and not reporting any errors in its log